# How Can I Benchmark A Recursive Function?

Tags: groovy, benchmarking

I'm using [GBench](http://code.google.com/p/gbench/). It works really cool for normal method Benchmarking. Now what I want is to benchmark an Recursive function.

Lets say I have :

```
def recursive() {
  //do something
  return recursive()
}
```

For this function I need to do Benchmark. Adding an `@Benchmark` at top of the method gives benchmark for each recursive call. But what I want is to get Benchmark for the whole `recursive` method.

Is it possible to so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make the initial call to the recursive function from a different, non-recursive function, and benchmark the non-recursive function.